# Getting Top 10 From list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, list, loops

Hi I have a problem getting top 10 products.

The scenario is: I have table of products which contain productid and date. I have method to get product by Id and loop it, but dont know how to get the most frequent product listed then.

I need to get top 10 products from a range date.

Basically I have list of products with their stock and list of orders with a product FK

I get the product FK from each order and get the top ten products which are most frequent from all the orders.

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: Please provide the code which you are using to get the data and the place where you are facing an issue.

Comment: What is the structure of the tables? What logic do you use to figure out "the most frequent product"?

Comment: Do you need to solve this in SQL or in C#/Linq?

Comment: How is this C# or asp.net related? You need to write an SQL query with `TOP` or `LIMIT` or equivalent. Please add the query that you use now to get ALL product records.

Comment: Don't loop, that's not what databases are for. It's so much slower than doing set based operations.

Comment: foreach(Order item in list)
{
Product p = new ProductsBL().getProductByid(item.productid);
top.add(p);
}

Comment: Do you use a database to fetch your products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply select your product list by creating a stored procedure and calling your table.

In the stored procedure you can select your product list by using 
`ORDER BY`

clause
for eg.

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_TABLE ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing based on our tag that you use a SQL database, and by your question that you list the same product multiple times... If that's the case you can do something like:

`Select * From "table" Group By "product" order by count(*) limit 10`

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged in sql and asp.net it should be an sql server db,

you can get **TOP** 10 product_id from product table which are dated **BETWEEN** the two dates(*if you are entering a date as a varchar or text you will need to convert it into datetime format*) and then order them by the date in **descending** order so this shall give you ten latest product.

here is an example code.

```
SELECT TOP 5 Product_ID FROM Product where Product.Dates between (SELECT convert(datetime, '2012-04-17 14:42:06.273', 120)) and (SELECT convert(datetime, '2012-04-19 10:39:08.477', 120)) order by Product.Dates desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help. You can partition both queries by date:

```sql
-- Top n-paid in all Depts:
SELECT * FROM 
 ( SELECT deptno, ename, sal
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by sal desc, ename) as row_num
    --, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal desc) ranks
    --, DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal desc) d_ranks
   FROM scott.emp )
WHERE row_num  <= 10 -- TOP 10 in all depts --

-- Between rows --
SELECT * FROM 
   ( SELECT deptno, ename, sal, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ename) Row_Num FROM scott.emp)
  WHERE Row_Num BETWEEN 5 and 10
```